# Using Popover over different iOS version (7,8,9)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios9, uipopovercontroller

I have an application which support three iOS versions viz. iOS 7,8,9 .In iOS 7,8 UIPopoverController is used to present view in popover.

Even though PopoverPresentationController  was introduced in iOS 8, the UIPopOverController worked fine until iOS 8.

Now while supporting iOS 9, UIPopoverController doesn't work as view is shown in full screen.

So PopoverPresentationController is used but as now application is build using iOS 9.2 SDK, popover are shown in full screen both in iOS 7,8 due to use of deprecated UIPopoverController.

I have changed approach from UIPopoverController to PopoverPresentationController for iOS 8 but in iOS 7 popover is still showing in full screen.

So in brief my problem is to present view in popover in application build using iOS 9.2 SDK but supporting iOS 7,8,9 devices.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the iOS version and use `UIPopoverController` for below iOS 8 versions

Comment: Yes I had used UIPopoverContorller for iOS 7 but when i compile my application with iOS 9.2 SDK , popover is shown in full screen .If application is compiled with iOS 9.1 or earlier SDK popover works fine .